# Viewing COM Addin code / get members of COM Addin Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, visual-studio-2010, vsto

Is there any way to

a) view the code of a COM-Addin **or**

b) get the members of an object that is created by a COM-Addin?

My employer considers buying a third-party MS Office add-in to create more fancy lookin charts in Excel. While working with the provided trial version we came across restrictions when customizing said fancy management charts.

Specifically, "we" want to do something like

```
ChartObject.SeriesCollection(i).HasDataLabels = FALSE
```

for individual series, which is not implemented in the UserControl.

Naturally, before buying, I wanted to test if there is a way to get that to work, since the tool already provides the option to bolden datalabels for individual series.

Having decent VBA add-in and VB.net experience and some novice Javascript skills this seemed doable (no experience with dll though).

It isn't.

The add-in is deployed as `msi`-file, which creates a folder structure in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local`. There I find

- several `.dll`-files
- a `.vsto`-file
- a folder containing varius html-sources, like

  - a `propertysheet.html` (seems to be the UserControl i see in Excel, see screenshot) and a corresponding `Property-Sheet.js`-File that sets values, controls behaviour etc.
  - additional `.js`-files, including `JQuery`, `Bootstrap` (etc) libraries and a custom file that supposedly contains the add-Ins code.
  - `.png`-icons and a couple of `.css`

This might not come unexpected, but the javascript code is basically unreadable, mainly because the created variables use names like `a868c7516d9e2e43` and there are no linebreaks.

I also suspect there is some additional VB or C# code somewhere in those `dll`-files, since i cannot find any readable function names in those `.js`-files.

Any help and any forwarding to sources explaining the connection between those heaps of files into an add-in is highly appreciated!

**Notes:**

- the aforementioned VBA-code is not an option, since the diagramms are recreated dynamically with the parameters stored in the file and the `ChartObject.SeriesCollection` I retrieve from my worksheet contains no `Series`-objects.
- the developer provides some basic tips for usage with vba [here](https://graphomate.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GCFEE/Visual+Basic+Scripting), however, this works only with the properties i see in the property window of the chart. I guess I want to look at the code of the `automationObject.setProperty`-sub to see if I can adjust it to our needs.
- tools: Office 2010, Visual Studio Express 2010, 7zip and Notepad++
- for each custom chart, a file is created in the `customXml`-folder of my `.xlsx`-File (can be seen using the 7zip archiver).

The following screen might give you an idea of what I'm dealing with (I'm using a simple chart on purpose here):

[image: Appendix 1]

Comment: Apparently their COM objects do not have properties, only the `setProperty` method that accepts property names as string. That is not friendly, and no, in that case you can't get the list of available properties other than from documentation or from disassembling the addin. To be extra sure, go to the VBA editor, add a reference to the addin and see what the object browser shows.

Comment: There's also a `getProperty`. Oddly, I cannot add a reference to any of the dlls.